# CSS | How to hide overflow in div where height set to 30px

Tags: html, css

I have a page where i want to show song title in a `div` where height set to `30px` 
If there is longer file title the div overflowed. I want to hide only pink `underline` used for that file title. 
Screenshot will describe more.

**Working : shown in image below. See** `Download Billo Tera Jatt by Jazzy B mp3 Song`

[![Works fine here][1]][1]

**not working. See** `Download Dubai Wale Shaikh (Manje Bistre) by Nimrat Khaira mp3 Song` and pink underline.

[![look like this when not works][2]][2]

CSS code

```
.title_1 {
height:30px;
margin-top:6px;
clear: both;
padding-top: 5px;
background: #33a6cf;
padding-right: 10px;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
border-bottom: 2px solid #B0B0B0;
color:#fff;

  }
  .title_1 .title_txt {
font-size: 12px;
border-bottom: 2px solid #FF007F;
padding: 0px 10px 9px 10px;
color: #fff;
 font-weight: 700;
```

Page code

```
 <div class="title_1"><span class="title_txt">Download <?=$getfile['name'].' by '.$Artist_Name[0]?> <?=$getfile['ext']?> Song</span></div>
```

I want longer title to be shown as showed in first screenshot.

Comment: Seeing as though the page itself is descriptive enough for the user to be able to see what they are downloading, could you not use `text-overflow:ellipsis` on the title? See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)

Comment: You have to define `width` and `text-overflow: ellipsis` in CSS for that particular text holding element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the next solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Game</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .container {
                width: 100px;
                white-space: nowrap;
                text-overflow: ellipsis;
                overflow: hidden;
                background: red;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">Bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

- `white-space: nowrap;` - makes that your text always has just one line.
- `text-overflow: ellipsis;` - for those '...' at the end of the line when it overflows its container.
- `overflow: hidden;` - you need to add this property if you wan that the previuos properties work correctly.

You can ommit the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` if you want.

Comment: Have you applied the CSS to the correct the wrapper? Make sure it's applied to `span.title_txt`. It may also need to have `display: inline-block;` applied to it as well.

Comment: In which class are you adding the properties I told you?  The title's container should has display: block; like a <div>. <span> is display: inline;

Comment: Exactly, @DanielJames!